# Custom Data is not inserting into database using $wpdb

Tags: database, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to insert data using $wpdb class. From the form, data is getting into the targeted variables without any problem as you can see I've checked it echoing them in each section.
`echo $FirstName."<br>";`
But for some reasons, it is not inserting into the database. It is showing error "Failed to add Horse" from that if statement below. What I've done wrong?

```
<?php
/**
 * Add Horse
 *
 * Shows the first intro screen on the account dashboard.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/dashboard.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     3.7.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}



       $FirstName               =       $_POST['firstname'];
       $LastName                =       $_POST['lastname'];
       $PlaceWoner              =       $_POST['placeowner'];
       $NameofHorse             =       $_POST['nameofthehorse'];
       $sex                     =       $_POST['sex'];
       $Horsebirthday           =       $_POST['datepicker'];
       $Breed                   =       $_POST['breed'];
       $crossbreedsorother      =       $_POST['crossbreedsorother'];
       $centimeter              =       $_POST['centimeter'];
       $specialfeature          =       $_POST['specialfeature'];
       $Injurydamange           =       $_POST['injurydamange'];
       $Injurydamageeffect      =       $_POST['injuries_damage_defects'];
       $Mameofpractitioner      =       $_POST['nameofpractitioner'];
       $lasttimedentist         =       $_POST['lasttimedentist'];
       $constitutie             =       $_POST['constitutie'];
       $Muscle                  =       $_POST['muscle'];
       $Traininglevel           =       $_POST['traininglevel'];
       $CurrentFoodandSupply    =       $_POST['current_food_and_supplements'];
       $Medication              =       $_POST['medication'];
       $HormonalImbalance       =       $_POST['hormonal_imbalance'];
       $eczema                  =       $_POST['eczema'];
       $lastWormcure            =       $_POST['last_worm_cure'];
       $cushing                 =       $_POST['cushing'];
       $InsulineRestistentie    =       $_POST['insuline_restistentie'];
       $laminitis               =       $_POST['laminitis'];
       $mondaysickness          =       $_POST['mondaysickness'];
       $liverFluke              =       $_POST['liverfluke'];
       $PSSM                    =       $_POST['PSSM'];
       $LymeDisease             =       $_POST['lymedisease'];
       $FungiInternalExternal   =       $_POST['FungiInternalExternal'];
       $InfectionsInternalExternal=     $_POST['InfectionsInternalExternal'];
       $Allergies               =       $_POST['Allergies'];
       $Mite                    =       $_POST['Mite'];
       $Splash                  =       $_POST['Splash'];
       $EOTRH                   =       $_POST['EOTRH'];
       $DonotMixMagnesium       =       $_POST['DonotMixMagnesium'];


        
       if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

                // Validating the all the fields----------------------
                if(trim($FirstName) === '') {
                        $formError[] = "First Name Can't be empty.";
                        $hasError = true;
                } else {
                        $FirstName = trim($FirstName);
                        $FirstName = sanitize_text_field($FirstName);
                        echo $FirstName."<br>";
                }
                
                if(trim($LastName) === '') {
                        $formError[] = "Last Name Can't be empty.";
                        $hasError = true;
                } else {
                        $LastName = trim($LastName);
                        $LastName = sanitize_text_field($LastName);
                        echo $LastName."<br>";
                }
                
                if($PlaceWoner === '') {
                        $formError[] = "Place Owner Can't be empty.";
                        $hasError = true;
                } else {
                        $PlaceWoner = sanitize_text_field($PlaceWoner);
                        echo $PlaceWoner."<br>";
                }

                if($NameofHorse === '') {
                        $formError[] = "Horse name Can't be empty.";
                        $hasError = true;
                } else {
                        $NameofHorse = sanitize_text_field($NameofHorse);
                        echo $NameofHorse."<br>";
                }

                if(!empty($sex)) {
                        $sex = sanitize_text_field($sex);
                        echo $sex."<br>";
                } else {
                        $sex = "";
                }

                if($Horsebirthday === '') {
                        $formError[] = "Please choose horse birthday.";
                        $hasError = true;
                } else {
                        $Horsebirthday = preg_replace("([^0-9/])", "", $Horsebirthday);
                        echo $Horsebirthday."<br>";
                }

                if(!empty($Breed)) {
                        $Breed = sanitize_text_field($Breed);
                        echo $Breed."<br>";
                } else {
                        $Breed = "";
                }

                if(!empty($crossbreedsorother)) {
                        $crossbreedsorother = sanitize_text_field($crossbreedsorother);
                        echo $crossbreedsorother."<br>";
                } else {
                        $crossbreedsorother = "";
                }

                if($centimeter === '') {
                        $formError[] = "Schofthoogte can't be empty";
                        $hasError = true;
                } else {
                        $centimeter = sanitize_text_field($centimeter);
                        echo $centimeter."<br>";
                }

                if(!empty($specialfeature)) {
                        $specialfeature = sanitize_textarea_field($specialfeature);
                        echo $specialfeature."<br>";
                } else {
                        $specialfeature = "";
                }

                if(!empty($Injurydamange)) {
                        $Injurydamange = sanitize_textarea_field($Injurydamange);
                        echo $Injurydamange."<br>";
                } else {
                        $Injurydamange = "";
                }

                if(!empty($Injurydamageeffect)) {
                        $Injurydamageeffect = sanitize_textarea_field($Injurydamageeffect);
                        echo $Injurydamageeffect."<br>";
                } else {
                        $Injurydamageeffect = "";
                }

                if(!empty($Mameofpractitioner)) {
                        $Mameofpractitioner = sanitize_textarea_field($Mameofpractitioner);
                        echo $Mameofpractitioner."<br>";
                } else {
                        $Mameofpractitioner = "";
                }

                if($lasttimedentist === '') {
                        $formError[] = "Date field can't be empty";
                        $hasError = true;
                } else {
                        $lasttimedentist = preg_replace("([^0-9/])", "", $lasttimedentist);
                        echo $lasttimedentist."<br>";
                }

                if($constitutie === '') {
                        $formError[] = "Constitutie can't be empty";
                        $hasError = true;
                } else {
                        $constitutie = sanitize_text_field($constitutie);
                        echo $constitutie."<br>";
                }

                if($Muscle === '') {
                        $formError[] = "Bespiering field can't be empty";
                        $hasError = true;
                } else {
                        $Muscle = sanitize_text_field($Muscle);
                        echo $Muscle."<br>";
                }

                if($Traininglevel === '') {
                        $formError[] = "Training level can't be empty";
                        $hasError = true;
                } else {
                        $Traininglevel = sanitize_text_field($Traininglevel);
                        echo $Traininglevel."<br>";
                }

                if($CurrentFoodandSupply === '') {
                        $formError[] = "Please provide special features";
                        $hasError = true;
                } else {
                        $CurrentFoodandSupply = sanitize_textarea_field($CurrentFoodandSupply);
                        echo $CurrentFoodandSupply."<br>";
                }

                if($Medication === '') {
                        $formError[] = "Medication can't be empty.";
                        $hasError = true;
                } else {
                        $Medication = sanitize_textarea_field($Medication);
                        echo $Medication."<br>";
                }

                if($HormonalImbalance === '') {
                        $formError[] = "Hormonal imbalance can't be empty.";
                        $hasError = true;
                } else {
                        $HormonalImbalance = sanitize_text_field($HormonalImbalance);
                        echo $HormonalImbalance."<br>";
                }

                if($eczema === '') {
                        $formError[] = "Eczema field can't be empty.";
                        $hasError = true;
                } else {
                        $eczema = sanitize_text_field($eczema);
                        echo $eczema."<br>";
                }

                if($lastWormcure === '') {
                        $formError[] = "Worm count date field can't be empty.";
                        $hasError = true;
                } else {
                        $lastWormcure = preg_replace("([^0-9/])", "", $lastWormcure);
                        echo $lastWormcure."<br>";
                }

                if(!empty($cushing)) {
                        $cushing = sanitize_text_field($cushing);
                        echo $cushing."<br>";
                } else {
                        $cushing = "";
                }

                if(!empty($InsulineRestistentie)) {
                        $InsulineRestistentie = sanitize_text_field($InsulineRestistentie);
                        echo $InsulineRestistentie."<br>";
                } else {
                        $InsulineRestistentie = "";
                }

                if(!empty($laminitis)) {
                        $laminitis = sanitize_text_field($laminitis);
                        echo $laminitis."<br>";
                } else {
                        $laminitis = "";
                }

                if(!empty($mondaysickness)) {
                        $mondaysickness = sanitize_text_field($mondaysickness);
                        echo $mondaysickness."<br>";
                } else {
                        $mondaysickness = "";
                }

                if(!empty($liverFluke)) {
                        $liverFluke = sanitize_text_field($liverFluke);
                        echo $liverFluke."<br>";
                } else {
                        $liverFluke = "";
                }

                if(!empty($PSSM)) {
                        $PSSM = sanitize_text_field($PSSM);
                        echo $PSSM."<br>";
                } else {
                        $PSSM = "";
                }

                if(!empty($LymeDisease)) {
                        $LymeDisease = sanitize_text_field($LymeDisease);
                        echo $LymeDisease."<br>";
                } else {
                        $LymeDisease = "";
                }

                if(!empty($FungiInternalExternal)) {
                        $FungiInternalExternal = sanitize_textarea_field($FungiInternalExternal);
                        echo $FungiInternalExternal."<br>";
                } else {
                        $FungiInternalExternal = "";
                }

                if(!empty($InfectionsInternalExternal)) {
                        $InfectionsInternalExternal = sanitize_textarea_field($InfectionsInternalExternal);
                        echo $InfectionsInternalExternal."<br>";
                } else {
                        $InfectionsInternalExternal = "";
                }

                if(!empty($Allergies)) {
                        $Allergies = sanitize_textarea_field($Allergies);
                        echo $Allergies."<br>";
                } else {
                        $Allergies = "";
                }

                if(!empty($Mite)) {
                        $Mite = sanitize_text_field($Mite);
                        echo $Mite."<br>";
                } else {
                        $Mite = "";
                }

                if(!empty($Splash)) {
                        $Splash = sanitize_text_field($Splash);
                        echo $Splash."<br>";
                } else {
                        $Splash = "";
                }

                if(!empty($EOTRH)) {
                        $EOTRH = sanitize_text_field($EOTRH);
                        echo $EOTRH."<br>";
                } else {
                        $EOTRH = "";
                }

                if(!empty($DonotMixMagnesium)) {
                        $DonotMixMagnesium = sanitize_text_field($DonotMixMagnesium);
                        echo $DonotMixMagnesium."<br>";
                } else {
                        $DonotMixMagnesium = "";
                }


                if(!isset($hasError)) {

                        global $wpdb;
                        
                        $currentUser    = get_current_user_id();
                        $tablename      = 'wp_horse_data';

                        $data = array(
                                'user_id'           => $currentUser,
                                'firstname'         => $FirstName,
                                'lastname'          => $LastName,
                                'placeowner'        => $PlaceWoner,
                                'nameofthehorse'    => $NameofHorse,
                                'sex'               => $sex,
                                'datepicker'        => $Horsebirthday,
                                'breed'             => $Breed,
                                'crossbreedsorother'=> $crossbreedsorother,
                                'centimeter'        => $centimeter,
                                'specialfeature'    => $specialfeature,
                                'injurydamange'     => $Injurydamange,
                                'injuries_damage_defects'=> $Injurydamageeffect,
                                'nameofpractitioner'=> $Mameofpractitioner,
                                'lasttimedentist'   => $lasttimedentist,
                                'muscle'            => $Muscle,
                                'traininglevel'     => $traininglevel,
                                'current_food_and_supplements'=> $CurrentFoodandSupply,
                                'medication'        => $Medication,
                                'hormonal_imbalance'=> $HormonalImbalance,
                                'eczema'            => $eczema,
                                'last_worm_cure'    => $lastWormcure,
                                'cushing'           => $cushing,
                                'insuline_restistentie'=> $InsulineRestistentie,
                                'laminitis'         => $laminitis,
                                'mondaysickness'    => $mondaysickness,
                                'liverfluke'        => $liverFluke,
                                'PSSM'              => $PSSM,
                                'lymedisease'       => $LymeDisease,
                                'FungiInternalExternal'=> $FungiInternalExternal,
                                'InfectionsInternalExternal'=> $InfectionsInternalExternal,
                                'Allergies'         => $Allergies,
                                'Mite'              => $Mite,
                                'Splash'            => $Splash,
                                'EOTRH'             => $EOTRH,
                                'DonotMixMagnesium' => $DonotMixMagnesium
                        );

                        $result = $wpdb->insert($tablename, $data, $format=NULL);

                        if($result == 1){
                                echo "New Horse Added";
                        }else {
                                echo "Failed to add Horse";
                        }
                }

        }
```

Comment: Remove $format=NULL & try to run query

Comment: No luck, still same issue.

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: Still, it is running this `else {echo "Failed to add Horse";}` block of code while I am trying to insert.

Comment: try to change $tablename = $user_table_name = $wpdb->prefix. "horse_data";

Comment: The [WPDB reference page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#show-and-hide-sql-errors) says that you could add `$wpdb->print_error();` to your final `else` block to show the last error. Or you could call `$wpdb->show_errors();` after `global $wpdb;` to cause database errors to be displayed as they happen.

Comment: I would  `print_r($data)` right before your `insert` to make sure all values are set properly, and that the formatting of each value corresponds to the data type in the database.